# MDL: How to switch sections with navigation drawer?

Tags: html, material-design-lite

Given the following sample code (with https://getmdl.io/ components included):

```html
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
  <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
    <header class="mdl-layout__header">
      <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
        <!-- Title -->
        <span class="mdl-layout-title">Testpage</span>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
      <span class="mdl-layout-title">Menu</span>
      <nav class="mdl-navigation">
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#scroll-tab-1">Test1</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#scroll-tab-2">Test2</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <main class="mdl-layout__content">
      <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel is-active" id="scroll-tab-1">
        <div class="page-content">
          <!-- Your content goes here -->
          Test1
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel" id="scroll-tab-2">
        <div class="page-content">
          <!-- Your content goes here -->
          Test2
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>
```

How to switch between the sections "scroll-tab-1" and "scroll-tab-2" using the navigation drawer elements?

It only works for me with tab bar elements:

```html
<link href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<body>
  <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
    <header class="mdl-layout__header">
      <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
        <!-- Title -->
        <span class="mdl-layout-title">Testpage</span>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-layout__tab-bar mdl-js-ripple-effect">
        <a href="#scroll-tab-1" class="mdl-layout__tab is-active">Test1</a>
        <a href="#scroll-tab-2" class="mdl-layout__tab">Test2</a>
      </div>
    </header>
    <main class="mdl-layout__content">
      <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel is-active" id="scroll-tab-1">
        <div class="page-content">
          <!-- Your content goes here -->
          Test1
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel" id="scroll-tab-2">
        <div class="page-content">
          <!-- Your content goes here -->
          Test2
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>
```

Surprisingly i can't find anything similar and all tutorials i found only have `href=""` navigation elements. Maybe my understanding is wrong on how to use the navigation drawer?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add relevent code in the question. What will happen if jsfiddle would stop, the question wouldn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I couldn't find an easy solution (it would be nice if they added an MD spec for vertical tab bars).
What I ended up doing is to create a function that shows the clicked element and hides the others. The function has one argument: the id of the element to show.
I call this function in the document.onload event passing it the id of the element that should be visible by default, and I call it in each onclick event of the mdl-navigation__link elements, passing it the id of the content element to show.

```js
<script>
 document.onload = show("dashboard");
 function show(targetId) {
  var elements = document.getElementById("content").querySelectorAll(".mdl-card");
  for (var i=0 ; i < elements.length; i++) {
   if (elements[i].id === targetId) {
    elements[i].style.display = 'block';
   } else {
    elements[i].style.display = 'none';
   }
  }
 }
</script>
```

```html
<div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
 <span class="mdl-layout-title">CSRS</span>
 <nav class="mdl-navigation">
    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#order" onclick="show('order')">Order Manager</a>
    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#inventory" onclick="show('inventory')">Inventory Manager</a>
    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#dahsboard" onclick="show('dashboard')">Dashboard</a>
    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#reports" onclick="show('reports')">Reports</a>
 </nav>
</div>
```